# Determine which binding was matched for a AMQP Message

Tags: php, binding, rabbitmq, amqp, matching

Is there any way to determine which of the bindings on the queue that I'm consuming messages from, caused to message to be routed to my queue?

I inspected the resulting Envelope object but can't find that information.

Use case:
I have an exclusive queue for my worker, which has multiple (100+ bindings) to various exchanges. For proper routing of the message in the worker I would like to know which binding(s) did match the message routing key.

Now I can implement a similar matching algorithm as RabbitMQ uses to determine this, but wondered if there was something built in.

Comment: I think the RabbitMQ firehose could give you that information